# What are the minimum options required to safely allow M2M field empty in DRF serializer Fields?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

There are four options: `required`, `allow_empty`, `allow_null` and `allow_blank` in DRF serializer fields. To allow empty M2M (Many-To-Many) field, is it **safe** to have just `allow_empty` as `True` or do other options need to be coordinated as well? Also, what is required for vice-versa?

**djangorestframework==3.8.2**

Comment: That entirely depends on your requirements. However, for save side, it better to have  `allow_blank`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django-rest-framework docs say:

> `allow_blank` - If set to `True` then the empty string should be considered a valid value. If set to `False` then the empty string is considered invalid and will raise a validation error. Defaults to `False`.

`allow_null` does exactly the same. But its usage is discouraged in favor of `allow_blank`. It is valid to set both `allow_blank=True` and `allow_null=True`, but doing so means that there will be two differing types of empty value permissible for string representations, which can lead to data inconsistencies and subtle application bugs.

`allow_blank` should be preferred for textual choices, and `allow_null` should be preferred for numeric or other non-textual choices.

`allow_empty` attribute has been added from **[django-rest-framework 3.2.x](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#allow_empty)**

`allow_empty` is used with `ListSerializer` or with `many=True` relationships.

source: **[django-rest-framework docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield)**

And speaking of fields other than `ManyToMany` like CHarfield or a choice field, using `allow_blank=True` implicitly says that this field is not required. But with the order of precedence if `allow_blank=True` is followed by a `required=True`, then the field is required.

Whereas `allow_empty` is used explicitly with ListSerializers to allow empty lists to be accepted by the serializer. By default, this is `True`. Which also says implicitly says: not required. So it is safe to add just `allow_empty=True` in an `M2M` relationship field.

Comment: I forgot to specify version, adding now. FYI: As of DRF 3.2+ `allow_empty` has been added. Still your answer is valueable :). Thanks.